# Create a procedure sorting by time imported from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, procedure

I'm trying to use two datetime values to sort in my query but I cant get it work.
It just complain on datetime formatting.

I got this error message when I try to execute following command

```
exec GetSingleAvailability @MachineID = 1002
```

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string.

Heres my procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSingleAvailability]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@MachineID int

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @Availabilitytime datetime
    DECLARE @TimeNow datetime

    set @Availabilitytime = (SELECT Availabilitytime FROM dbo.machines Where MachineID = @MachineID)
    set @TimeNow = (SELECT GETDATE() AS time)
        DECLARE @query nvarchar(150)
        set @query = 'SELECT AVG(effectively) FROM ['+ Convert(nvarchar, @MachineID) +'] WHERE time between '+ @Availabilitytime +' and '+ @TimeNow +''
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @query 

END
```

Comment: Check out the possibility of using parameters with [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) instead of concatenation for putting the values into the query. You should also have a look at [`quotename()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and apply it to the table name you're concatenating into the query.

Comment: And you should really check your design. One table per machine doesn't seem right. Consider using one table for all machines with the machine's ID in a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your procedure may need to be fixed a bit:

```
ALTER Proc GetSingleAvailability (@MachineID int) as
begin
    set nocount on
    declare @Availabilitytime datetime, @TimeNow datetime, @query nvarchar(150)

    select
          @Availabilitytime =
                (select AvailabilityTime from machines where MachineID = @MachineID)
        , @TimeNow = getDate()
        , @query = N'select avg(effectively) from '
                + quoteName(convert(nvarchar, @MachineID))
                + N' where [time] between '
                + quoteName(convert(nvarchar, @Availabilitytime, 120), nchar(39))
                + N' and '
                + quoteName(convert(nvarchar, @TimeNow, 120), nchar(39))

    execute sp_executesql @query
end
```

Change `120` to `8` if you only need the time (`hh:mm:ss`) part.

Comment: Xabi, than you! It is a much better solution than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution like this:

```
    USE [MITestdb]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetSingleAvailability]    Script Date: 2020-09-11 20:10:47 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSingleAvailability]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@MachineID int

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @Availabilitytime datetime
    DECLARE @TimeNow datetime

    set @Availabilitytime = (SELECT Availabilitytime FROM dbo.machines Where MachineID = @MachineID)
    set @TimeNow = (SELECT GETDATE())
        DECLARE @query nvarchar(150)
        set @query = 'SELECT AVG(effectively) FROM ['+ Convert(nvarchar, @MachineID) +'] WHERE time between @qAvailabilitytime and @qTimeNow'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @query,
    N'@qAvailabilitytime datetime, @qTimeNow datetime', 
        @qAvailabilitytime = @Availabilitytime, @qTimeNow = @TimeNow

END
```